# File Appear on Untracked list Git Commit but not on Git Status

Tags: ios, xcode, github

I'm working on iOS project and when I'm trying to do "git commit -a" command in terminal, it gives list of untracked files:

> Untracked files:
>
> (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
>
> *.xcodeproj/

Meanwhile, when I try to do "git status" command, the console does not list it as untracked files, but list

> *.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj

as modified file.

Do I need still to push it?

Answer (score 0):

Before pushing anything, you would need to add and commit those untracked files.

```
git add *.xcodeproj/
```

Or to add it to the .gitignore file and ignore it.

The difference of display between comit and status is probably due to the `--untracked-files` option.

```
-u[<mode>]
--untracked-files[=<mode>]
```

> Show untracked files.
>
> The mode parameter is optional (defaults to `all`), and is used to specify the handling of untracked files; when `-u` is not used, the default is normal, i.e. show untracked files and directories.
>
> The possible options are:
>
> - **`no`** - Show no untracked files
> - **`normal`** - Shows untracked files and directories
> - **`all`** - Also shows individual files in untracked directories.