# How to shear image in Android?

Tags: android, image-manipulation

is it possible to shear image in Android? Seems I can't find any tutorial of it.

Comment: you need to put some sample image or any code.

Comment: this link may help you, its a java code, you can use the concept to shear the image http://bingjava.appspot.com/model?id=1384

Comment: Why did you delete http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390657/file-appear-on-untracked-list-git-commit-but-not-on-git-status/11391624#11391624 ? At least, leave it for other git users. They can benefit fro it.

Comment: @VonC: sorry i unintentionally deleted it, i'm trying to undelete it

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you've found the solution, but just in case, I think this is what you needed:

```
Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), drawable.sample);
int width = src.getWidth();
int height = src.getHeight();
float skewX = 5.0;
float skewY = 6.0;
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setSkew(skewX, skewY);
Bitmap img = Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This May Help you

Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.flower_blue);

```
        Bitmap croppedBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0,
                bitmapOrg.getWidth() / 2, bitmapOrg.getHeight());
        int h = bitmapOrg.getHeight();
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapOrg, 10, 10, paint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(croppedBmp, 10, 10 + h + 10, paint);
```

Comment: sorry i mean shear, not share