# Adjusting an image to any given quadrilateral

Tags: java, image, graphics

I have a cube which can be rotated in x,y and z direction.I figured out how to draw its wireframe and how to fill the sides with one colour per side.But my attempts to texture the cube failed.All possibilities to adapt an image to non-cubic shapes I have found use an external library but I want to do it in pure java.

Here is what i tried:

```
  Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
    polygon.addPoint((int)p[1][x]+200, (int)p[1][y]+200);
    polygon.addPoint((int)p[2][x]+200, (int)p[2][y]+200);
    polygon.addPoint((int)p[6][x]+200, (int)p[6][y]+200);
    polygon.addPoint((int)p[5][x]+200, (int)p[5][y]+200);

    g.setClip(polygon);
    g.drawImage(tex, (int)p[1][x]+200, (int)p[1][y]+200, null);
    g.setClip(new Rectangle(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight()));
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to transform the image, you can shear, rotate, translate etc on your image...

to do so you need an [Affine-matrix](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) to transform the image...

once you know how to use the matrix you can also use it to transform your points, it's a very comfortable way

see also the a question on [how to shear a bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392821/how-to-shear-image-in-android):

btw: nice work, there doing it in pure java!

sorry, when i'm only responding in sending links, but maybe you can be a bit more specific on your ptoblem =)

Comment: Thank you :), I'll try to use the _Affine-Matrix_.  
Doing it in pure java is far more fun, isn't it? :D

Comment: thanks for motivating me :) I can't even imagine to stop coding.